# Fullcalendar: How can get selected start and selected end datetime on fullcalendar through calendar object?

Tags: javascript, jquery, fullcalendar

I have gone through other post of fullcalendar but i couldn't fine what i need.

In "Select" callback event under fullcalendar, i could get start,end datetime values which are selected by user. I want this values through calendar object as i need to use this in other function.

http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/docs/selection/select_callback/

Can any one please share me , how to get start/end value through calendar object ?

Comment: could you please elaborate more, you are getting start and end date then why do you need start and end date through calendar object ?

Comment: Basically, i need to use selected start/end value into one function which is called while clicking on submitting the dialog and in that function, i could not have start/end value which is found at select callback method.

As alternative, In select callback method, i need to set start/end value to global variable and use those global variable into function. it works by this way.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

```
$(document).ready(function () {
        // Calendar
        var date = new Date();
        var d = date.getDate();
        var m = date.getMonth();
        var y = date.getFullYear();

        var calendar = $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
            header: {
                left: 'prev,next today',
                center: 'title',
                right: 'month'
            },
            selectable: true,
            selectHelper: true,
            select: function (start, end, allDay) {
                var title = prompt('Event Title:'+start+' '+end);
                if (title) {
                    calendar.fullCalendar('renderEvent',
                        {
                            title: title,
                            start: start,
                            end: end,
                            allDay: allDay
                        },
                        true // make the event "stick"
                    );
                    //$('.fc-day-content').html('<div style="position: relative; height: 0px;">xxx</div>');
                }
                calendar.fullCalendar('unselect');
            },
            editable: true,
        });
        // Calendar end
    });
```

SEE "start" and "end" in prompt